# Showing a measurable function is zero a.e.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $f:(a,b)\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$ be a non-negative measurable function such that $\int_{a}^{b}{f}dx=0$.  Then $f=0$ a.e.

To prove this result, let $A:=\{x\in{(a,b)}:f(x)>0\}$. Then on contradiction suppose $m(A)>0$. Now my confusion is can we assume $A$ an open subset of $(a,b)$ without loss of generality?

There are other methods too to establish this result but I just wanna make sure whether we can assume $A$ an open subset of $(a,b)$ or not.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set of positive measure does not necessarily have an open subset.  An example is the set of irrationals on $[0,1]$, i.e. $[0,1] \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.
So you cannot conclude necessarily that there exists open $A$ on which $f > 0$.

However, it is the case that if a set is measurable, it differs from an open set on a set of measure zero.  So you can find $A$ open such that $f > 0$ almost everywhere on $A$, which should be good enough to justify what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to show that for some $\lambda>0$, the set $\{x\in (a,b): f(x)>\lambda\}$ is non-empty. Once you can show such a $\lambda$ exists, then we'd have \begin{align*}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\ dx\ge \int_{\{x\in (a,b): f(x)>\lambda\}}f(x)\ dx>\lambda\cdot |\{x\in (a,b): f(x)>\lambda\}| >0
\end{align*}

(Hint: $\{x\in (a,b): f(x)>0\}=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x\in (a,b): f(x)>n^{-1}\}$.